# Guidewire - Database Bean Version Conflict - com.guidewire.pl.system.exception.ConcurrentDataChangeException

Tags: guidewire

Can someone help me to identify the root cause and how to resolve this issue?

The object you are trying to update was 'WorksheetData:pc:XXXX', and it was changed by System at 03/14/2022 7:04 PM. Please cancel and retry your change.

When I checked it in the guidewire display.properties

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very vague and not much context is available.
But in general, this error means that the current object being updated is already being updated by another person/process.

Is this a webservice, UI action or any other specific functionality?

There can be several ways to fix this with the most common one being a retry counter.
Catch the exception and retry the operation again. Depending on where you are facing this issue, different solutions can be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the bundle has been already committed and the period is now locked and users or system cannot change the locked branch. Usually to avoid these errors use touch() property of the bundle instance as it increase the bundle version property.